# How to filter Raster or only plot certain raster category values in R?

Tags: r, plot, filter, leaflet, raster

I have multiple years of Land Cover Raster data in R whose attribute tables look like this (both screenshot and code):

```
ID   COUNT   CLASSNAME
11  525631  Open Water                          0   0   255 0.000000    0.000000    1.000000
500 1176    Developed-Upland Deciduous Forest   64  61  168 0.250980    0.239216    0.658824
501 3965    Developed-Upland Evergreen Forest   68  79  137 0.266667    0.309804    0.537255
502 3619    Developed-Upland Mixed Forest   102 119 205 0.400000    0.466667    0.803922
503 49181   Developed-Upland Herbaceous 122 142 245 0.478431    0.556863    0.960784
504 16592   Developed-Upland Shrubland  158 170 215 0.619608    0.666667    0.843137
505 42867   Developed - Low Intensity   255 122 143 1.000000    0.478431    0.560784
506 21570   Developed - Medium Intensity    253 44  79  0.992157    0.172549    0.309804
507 12451   Developed - High Intensity  173 0   28  0.678431    0.000000    0.109804
25  80384   Developed-Roads 1   1   1   0.003922    0.003922    0.003922
```

[image]

I am trying to plot only the following categories in leaflet below. I have tried recoding, spatial filtering, binning with colorBin, and am looking for a new method, either by filtering the data directly or altering the plot.

```
Developed - Forested", "Developed - herbaceous or shrubland", 
"Developed - Medium Intensity", "Developed - High Intensity", "Cropland",
"Tree Cover 0-50%", "Tree Cover 50-100%", "Shrub Cover", "Herb Cover 0-50%", "Herb Cover 50-100%")
```

I am looking for a final product like this (with the correct values instead of the colors below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just `filter()` your data before plotting it?

Without a reproducible example, here's just an idea:

```
filter_classnames <- c("Developed - Forested", "Developed - herbaceous or shrubland", 
"Developed - Medium Intensity", "Developed - High Intensity", "Cropland",
"Tree Cover 0-50%", "Tree Cover 50-100%", "Shrub Cover", "Herb Cover 0-50%", "Herb Cover 50-100%")

filtered_data <- your_data %>%
  filter(CLASSNAMES %in% filter_classnames)
```

Comment: the problem is filtering the attribute table does not necessarily filter the whole raster image. I will try this though